# COBOL layout parser in Python

Tags: python, parsing, cobol

I don't know anything about parsers but I had to write something to read COBOL for a work project. What are some things that I could improve with my Python coding and parser design?

Note: This isn't COBOL feature complete yet, just the things I need for the project.

```
"""
Parse COBOL copybook files to a Python list for EBCDIC reading
"""

#! /usr/bin/env python

import re
from os import path

# Only the handful I care about really
COBOL_KEYWORDS = {"COMP-3", "PIC", "REDEFINES", "OCCURS", "TIMES", "SIGN", "IS"}


class COBOLParser:
    """
    Takes a file path as an argument. Run the parse method on returned object
    to convert to a python readable format.
    """

    def __init__(self, file: str):
        if not path.isfile(file):
            raise FileNotFoundError
        self.file = file

        # This here object keeps track of what level ID groups are in in. This
        # is not needed in the final data, but is nescessary for determining
        # what level to place a new item on after leaving a group so it is
        # stored seperately
        self.group_levels = []

    def parse(self) -> list:
        """
        Parse and return self.file as a list of python dictionaries
        """
        parse_out = []
        with open(self.file, "rt") as cobol_file:
            line_number = 0
            previous_field_level = 0
            previous_group_level = 0
            unfinished_item = {}
            for line in cobol_file:
                line_number += 1

                # skip comment lines and empty lines
                if not line.strip() or line.strip()[0] == "*":
                    continue

                parse_out = self.parse_line(parse_out, line, line_number)

                # Check for duplicate names
                group = (
                    self._item_level(parse_out, self.group_levels[-1][1])
                    if self.group_levels
                    else parse_out
                )
                if (
                    group
                    and not unfinished_item
                    and group[-1:][0]["Name"] != "FILLER"
                    and group[-1:][0]["Name"]
                    in [item["Name"] for item in group[:-1]]
                ):
                    raise InvalidCOBOLError(
                        line_number, "Duplicate names in a group."
                    )

                # Check for proper line ending
                if (
                    unfinished_item
                    and unfinished_item["Name"]
                    != self._lowest_dict(parse_out)["Name"]
                ):
                    raise InvalidCOBOLError(
                        line_number - 1, "Unended line was not continued."
                    )

                # Make sure that the level is lesser than or equal to the last
                # field level if previous level is a field. Then set a new
                # value for previous_line_level.
                if (
                    not unfinished_item
                    and previous_field_level
                    and int(line.strip()[:2]) > previous_field_level
                ):
                    raise InvalidCOBOLError(
                        line_number, "Field has sub entries at line {}"
                    )

                # If a group was created the item after the group needs to be a
                # member of said group, otherwise, raise error
                if (
                    not unfinished_item
                    and previous_group_level
                    and int(line.strip()[:2]) <= previous_group_level
                ):
                    raise InvalidCOBOLError(
                        line_number - 1, "Group has no sub elements at line {}."
                    )

                # Save information about last read line for easier error
                # checking.
                if (
                    not unfinished_item
                    and self._lowest_dict(parse_out)["Type"] == "Field"
                ):
                    previous_field_level = int(line.strip()[:2])
                    previous_group_level = 0
                elif not unfinished_item:
                    previous_group_level = int(line.strip()[:2])
                    previous_field_level = 0

                # Check for EOL character in string
                line_ended_check = r"(\w|\d|\))+\.(\s|$)"
                if not re.search(line_ended_check, line):
                    unfinished_item = self._lowest_dict(parse_out)
                else:
                    unfinished_item = {}

        return parse_out

    def parse_line(
        self, out_builder: list, line: str, line_number: int
    ) -> list:
        """
        Parses a COBOL line and creates a new item in the output builder. If
        the line is a continuation of a previous line, just add the new info to
        the previously added entry.
        """
        if out_builder:
            last_element = self._lowest_dict(out_builder)
        else:
            last_element = {}

        items = [x for x in line.strip().split()]

        # Strip out closing periods from items, then strip out items that come
        # after the period
        for item in items:
            if item[-1:] == ".":
                line_ended = True
                last_item = items.index(item)
                items = items[: last_item + 1]
                items[last_item] = items[last_item][:-1]
            else:
                line_ended = False

        try:
            # Check first item (should be level if not a line continuation)
            # Level should be two digits, representing a number between 01 and
            # 49. COBOL standards also allow 66 and 88 as levels with specific
            # rules. These are not supported yet but if they are in the future
            # replace below regex with the following: (?!00)(66|88|[0-4][[0-9])
            if re.match(r"(?!00)[0-4][0-9]", items[0]):
                current_level = items[0]

            # Check whether line is a continuation of previous line
            # As of right now, only PIC and Usage are allowed to continue
            # onto another line, (both only existing on fields
            elif (
                items[0] == "PIC"
                and last_element
                and "Format" not in last_element.keys()
            ):
                last_element["Format"] = self._clause_value(items, "PIC")
                last_element["Type"] = "Field"

                # Check if continued line also has usage clause
                # PIC is always two items long, check after
                if len(items) == 3 and self._valid_usage(items[2]):
                    last_element["Usage"] = items[2]
                return out_builder
            elif (
                last_element
                and last_element["Type"] == "Field"
                and self._valid_usage(items[0])
                and "Usage" not in last_element.keys()
            ):
                last_element["Usage"] = items[0]
                return out_builder
            else:
                raise InvalidCOBOLError(
                    line_number, "Input does not resemble COBOL at line {}"
                )

            # At this point we know this is a new field or group. Get the group
            # name and save it in a dictionary representing the new item. Also
            # check for invalid names
            new_item = {"Name": items[1]}

            # Get the list of fields for the group the current item belongs to
            current_group = self._item_level(out_builder, int(current_level))
            if new_item["Name"] in COBOL_KEYWORDS:
                raise InvalidCOBOLError(
                    line_number,
                    "Field or group name at line {} matches a COBOL keyword",
                )

            try:
                clause_error = InvalidCOBOLError(
                    line_number,
                    "A clause was declared but no definition was given.",
                )
                if "REDEFINES" in items:
                    new_item["Redefines"] = self._clause_value(
                        items, "REDEFINES"
                    )
                    if new_item["Redefines"] in COBOL_KEYWORDS:
                        raise clause_error

                if "OCCURS" in items:
                    if items[items.index("OCCURS") + 2] != "TIMES":
                        raise clause_error

                    try:
                        new_item["Occurs"] = int(
                            self._clause_value(items, "OCCURS")
                        )
                    except ValueError:
                        raise InvalidCOBOLError(
                            line_number,
                            "Occurs clause must specify an integer value at line {}.",
                        )

                if "PIC" not in items and line_ended:
                    # Append the newly added group to group_levels
                    self.group_levels.append(
                        (new_item["Name"], int(current_level))
                    )
                    new_item["Type"] = "Group"
                    new_item["Fields"] = []
                    current_group.append(new_item)
                    return out_builder

                # Item is field
                new_item["Type"] = "Field"
                if "PIC" in items:
                    new_item["Format"] = self._clause_value(items, "PIC")

                    if new_item["Format"] in COBOL_KEYWORDS:
                        raise clause_error

                    # Check for usage clause.
                    usage_index = items.index("PIC") + 2
                    if len(items) > usage_index:
                        if self._valid_usage(items[usage_index]):
                            new_item["Usage"] = items[usage_index]
                        else:
                            raise InvalidCOBOLError(
                                line_number,
                                (
                                    "Usage clause does not match an existing "
                                    "definition at line {}"
                                ),
                            )

            except IndexError:
                raise clause_error

            current_group = self._item_level(out_builder, int(current_level))
            current_group.append(new_item)
            return out_builder

        except IndexError:
            raise InvalidCOBOLError(
                line_number, "Input does not resemble COBOL at line {}"
            )

    def _item_level(self, struct: list, current_level: int) -> list:
        """
        Returns a list corresponding what group an item should belong to.
        """
        if not struct or not self.group_levels:
            return struct
        # We only care about the last level of a matching group. Check groups
        # in reverse.
        if current_level > self.group_levels[-1][1]:
            return self._lowest_list(struct)
        for group in self.group_levels[::-1]:

            # Return the fields of the first group that has a lower level than
            # the current item's level.
            if group[1] < current_level:
                return self._lowest_list(struct, group[0])
        return struct

    def _lowest_dict(self, struct: list) -> dict:
        """
        Returns the deepest dictionary at the bottom of provided structure.
        """
        last_element = struct[-1:][0]
        if "Fields" in last_element.keys() and last_element["Fields"]:
            return self._lowest_dict(last_element["Fields"])
        return last_element

    def _lowest_list(self, struct: list, name: str = None) -> list:
        """
        Returns the deepest list at the bottom of provided stucture. If a name
        parameter is provided, stop searching and return list with matching
        name.
        """
        if not struct:
            return struct
        last_element = struct[-1]
        if (
            name
            and last_element["Name"] == name
            and "Fields" in last_element.keys()
        ):
            return last_element["Fields"]
        if "Fields" in last_element.keys():
            return self._lowest_list(last_element["Fields"])
        return struct

    @staticmethod
    def _clause_value(items: list, clause: str) -> str:
        """
        Returns the item from a list of items following the provided clause.
        """
        value = items[items.index(clause) + 1]
        return value

    @staticmethod
    def _valid_usage(usage: str) -> bool:
        """
        Returns bool indicating whether provided usage is valid or not.
        """
        # Not really an indication of valid usages as much as a list of what
        # usages the EBCDIC reader we use supports.
        valid_usages = ["COMP-3"]
        return usage in valid_usages

class InvalidCOBOLError(Exception):
    """
    Produces an error message with a line number showing which line of code
    contains the Invalid COBOL. msg parameter should contain a set of empty
    square brackets, although if not, a set will be appended to the end of the
    message.
    """

    def __init__(self, line, msg=None):
    if msg is None:
        # Try to not let this happen
        msg = (
            "There was an unspecified error while parsing the COBOL at "
            "line {}. Please contact a developer for assistance."
        )
    elif not "{}" in msg:
        msg = msg + " (Line {})."
    msg = msg.format(line)
    super(InvalidCOBOLError, self).__init__(msg)
```

Comment: An alternative approach is to look at **cb2xml** https://sourceforge.net/projects/cb2xml/) it will convert the Cobol to Xml. cb2xml is written java but there is an example of reading the Xml in python. cb2xml. Alternative cb2xml is written using sablecc; sablecc can generate pyhtonas well as java.

Comment: there is also stingray https://sourceforge.net/projects/stingrayreader/

Comment: There are a lot of quirks in `COBOL`, the existing parsers will deal with many of them. Take `comp-3` it can also be written as `computational-3`, it can be specified with/without usage and at either field or group level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`group[-1:][0]["Name"]`

This expression is reused, so assign it to a variable name.

`in [item["Name"] for item in group[:-1]]`

For a membership test, a set is a better idea than a list.

`int(line.strip()[:2])`

This is reused a bunch of times, so make a variable.

`line_ended_check = r"(\w|\d|\))+\.(\s|$)"`

You shouldn't initialize this regex where it is. It needs to be compiled once, outside of all of your parsing loops, using `re.compile`.

`elif not "{}" in msg:`

You should probably use `elif "{}" not in msg:` .